# shinydashboard does not work with uiOutput

Tags: r, shiny

I setup the UI in server.R for more control, but shinyDashboard does not work when defined in server.R.
I use this method with navBarPage without problems.

This code works

```
library(shiny)     
library(shinydashboard)

ui     <- dashboardPage(  dashboardHeader( ), 
                          dashboardSidebar(),
                          dashboardBody()   )

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {   })
runApp(list(ui= ui, server = server))
```

But this one just show an empty page

```
ui     <-  uiOutput('dash')
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) { 
  output$dash <- renderUI({   
    dashboardPage(dashboardHeader( ), 
                  dashboardSidebar(),
                  dashboardBody()  )
  }) 
})
runApp(list(ui= ui, server = server))
```

This is an example using navBarPage, that works fine

```
ui     <-  uiOutput('nav')
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) { 
  output$nav <- renderUI({   
    navbarPage("App Title",  
               tabPanel("Tab 1"),    
               tabPanel("Tab 2")  ) 
  })
})  
runApp(list(ui= ui, server = server))
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think that you can use only a `uiOutput` to create a dashboard. I'm assuming that your goal is to create a dynamic dashboard. For that you need to define the header, body and side bar in your UI and use functions such as `renderMenu` on SERVER to create it. Here is an example to create a dashboard with all the UI defined in the SERVER.

```R
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "My Page"),
  dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenuOutput("sideBar_menu_UI")),
  dashboardBody(
    uiOutput("body_UI"),
    uiOutput("test_UI")
  )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) { 
  output$sideBar_menu_UI <- renderMenu({
    sidebarMenu(id = "sideBar_Menu",
      menuItem("Menu 1", tabName="menu1_tab", icon = icon("calendar")),
      menuItem("Menu 2", tabName="menu2_tab", icon = icon("database"))
    )
  }) 
  output$test_UI <- renderUI ({
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "menu1_tab", uiOutput("menu1_UI")),
      tabItem(tabName = "menu2_tab", uiOutput("menu2_UI"))
    )
  })
  output$body_UI <- renderUI ({
    p("Default content in body outsite any sidebar menus.")
  })
  output$menu1_UI <- renderUI ({
    box("Menu 1 Content")
  })
  output$menu2_UI <- renderUI ({
    box("Menu 2 Content")
  })

})

runApp(list(ui= ui, server = server))
```

In this example,  a menu for the sidebar is not selected by default and the content of `body_UI` will be visible all the time. If you want that your dashboard starts on a specific menu, put the `sidebarMenu` in your UI. Also you can delete the `body_UI`.

Comment: My actual usage is a bit more complex. I use dashboardPage inside a navbarPage, that is dynamically generated in the server. There is a single line in my UI.R,  uiOutput("App"). Because dashboardPage cannot be called using renderUI, this approach fails. But I think you are correct, dashboardPage cannot be implemented this way.

Comment: this is tremendously helpful. I was not aware that you can use the uiOutput server side to feed it into another renderUI.