# R shinydashboard: Mix of dynamic and static tabItems for various menusubitems

Tags: r, shiny, menuitem, shinydashboard

I am building an app with three segments:

1. Overview
2. Detailed results
3. Help

The detailed result section should show results of many sub-items, one at the time.

I am interested to the Result section to be a single tab, because I don't want to write code each tab for each sub-item. Each sub-item has identical, in the example a histogram.

When I run the example though, I loose the ID of the subitems.
Is it possible to have a layout like this but to keep the ID's of all menuitems and menusubitems?

Happy to look at alternative approaches.

*An example to illustrate the issue is below. The solution will show the table in overview, a histogram in results for any of the sub-items and the HTML output in the help section.*

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(), 
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(id = "SideBarMENU", 

                menuItem("Overview", tabName = "OVERVIEW", selected = TRUE),
                menuItem("Results",  startExpanded = TRUE,
                         menuSubItem("Sepal.Length", tabName = "RESULTS"),
                         menuSubItem("Sepal.Width" , tabName = "RESULTS"),
                         menuSubItem("Petal.Length", tabName = "RESULTS"),
                         menuSubItem("Petal.Width" , tabName = "RESULTS")
                ), 
                menuItem("Help", tabName = "HELP")
    )

  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem("OVERVIEW", 
              box("Overview box", 
                  tableOutput("overview"))
      ),
      tabItem("RESULTS", 
              box("Results box", 
                  plotOutput("results")
              )
      ),
      tabItem("HELP", 
              box("HELP box", 
                  textOutput("help"))
      ) 
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {


  data <- reactive({

    print(input$SideBarMENU)

    if(input$SideBarMENU %in% names(iris)){
      iris[[input$SideBarMENU]]
    } else {
      rnorm(100, 1000, 10)
    }
  })


  output$results <- renderPlot({
    hist(data())
  })


  output$overview <- renderTable({
    head(iris)
  })



  output$help <- renderText({
    HTML("A wiki is a website on which users collaboratively.....")
  })



}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you need two components:

1. Dynamic content / plots
2. Dynamic dashboard body

The first part is more easy:

**1. Dynamic content / plots**

You can create the outputs in a loop as explained in a few other SO posts:

```
  lapply(nms, function(name){
    output[[name]] <- renderUI ({
      box("Results Box", plotOutput(paste0("plot_", name)))
    })

    output[[paste0("plot_", name)]] <- renderPlot({
      hist(iris[[input$SideBarMENU]], main = "")
    })
  })
```

**2. Dynamic dashboard body**

This part is more complicated. You need dynamic `tabitems()` and they have to be mixed with static parts. In order to hand over a list of `tabitem()` to `tabitems()` you can use `do.call(tabItems, ..)` for converting it, see the link below. To combine them with the static elements, convert the static ones as `list()` elements and combine them all in a `list()` before calling `do.call(tabItems, ..)`.

```
  output$tabItms <- renderUI ({
    itemsDyn <- lapply(nms, function(name){
      tabItem(tabName = name, uiOutput(name))
    })

    items <- c(
      list(
        tabItem("OVERVIEW", 
              box("Overview box", 
                  tableOutput("overview"))
        )
      ),  
      itemsDyn,
      list(
        tabItem("HELP", 
                box("HELP box", 
                    textOutput("help"))
        )
      )
    )
    do.call(tabItems, items)
  })
```

Similar components can be found here: [shinydashboard does not work with uiOutput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38826893/shinydashboard-does-not-work-with-uioutput) 
and for looping `tabItems()` here: [How to make a function in a for loop or lapply loop in a tabItem dashboard shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46909890/how-to-make-a-function-in-a-for-loop-or-lapply-loop-in-a-tabitem-dashboard-shiny).

**Note:**

I modify `names(iris)`:

```
nms <- gsub("[.]", "", names(iris))
names(iris) <- nms
```

because no dots are allowed for the tabItem names.

**Reproducible example:**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

nms <- gsub("[.]", "", names(iris))
names(iris) <- nms


ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(), 
  dashboardSidebar(
    uiOutput("menu")
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    uiOutput("tabItms")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$tabItms <- renderUI ({
    itemsDyn <- lapply(nms, function(name){
      tabItem(tabName = name, uiOutput(name))
    })

    items <- c(
      list(
        tabItem("OVERVIEW", 
              box("Overview box", 
                  tableOutput("overview"))
        )
      ),  
      itemsDyn,
      list(
        tabItem("HELP", 
                box("HELP box", 
                    textOutput("help"))
        )
      )
    )
    do.call(tabItems, items)
  })

  lapply(nms, function(name){
    output[[name]] <- renderUI ({
      box("Results Box", plotOutput(paste0("plot_", name)))
    })

    output[[paste0("plot_", name)]] <- renderPlot({
      hist(iris[[input$SideBarMENU]], main = "")
    })
  })



  output$menu <- renderUI({
    sidebarMenu(id = "SideBarMENU", 
                menuItem("Overview", tabName = "OVERVIEW", selected = TRUE),
                menuItem("Results", id = "resultChoice",  startExpanded = TRUE,
                         lapply(nms, function(name) {
                           menuSubItem(name, tabName = name)
                         })
                ), 
                menuItem("Help", tabName = "HELP")
    )
  })

  output$overview <- renderTable({
    head(iris)
  })

  output$help <- renderText({
    HTML("A wiki is a website on which users collaboratively.....")
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Unfortunately in the initial view no tab is selected. `selected = TRUE` has no effect. Any idea how to change that?